# Why does the arrow not draw in my React code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My code contains a toolbar, it's about a dropdown. When pass is selected it should enable the ability to create an arrow by drag and dropping on the canvas. I use JS React with useState and useEffect. Here's the important snippets:

```
    const handleFieldMouseDown = (event) => {
      const rect = canvasRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
      const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
      const y = event.clientY - rect.top;
      if (addingArrow) {
        setArrowStartPoint({ x, y });
      } else if (addingArea) {
        setAreaStart({ x, y });
      // Handle other elements as usual
    };
  }
  
  const handleFieldMouseMove = useCallback((event) => {
    const rect = canvasRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
    const y = event.clientY - rect.top;
    if (addingArrow && arrowStartPoint) {
     drawArrow(arrowStartPoint, { x, y });
    } else if (addingArea && areaStart) {
      setPreviewArea({
        x: Math.min(areaStart.x, x),
        y: Math.min(areaStart.y, y),
        width: Math.abs(x - areaStart.x),
        height: Math.abs(y - areaStart.y)
      });
    }
  
    // Call drawArrow to update the arrow drawing
    
  }, [arrowStartPoint, addingArrow, addingArea, areaStart]);

  const handleFieldMouseUp = (event) => {
    const rect = canvasRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
    const y = event.clientY - rect.top;
    if (addingArrow) {
      
      setArrowEndPoint({ x, y });
      const newArrow = {
        start: arrowStartPoint,
        end: arrowEndPoint,
        type: arrowType,
      };
      drawArrow(arrowStartPoint, arrowEndPoint);
      setArrows((arrows) => [...arrows, newArrow]);
      setArrowStartPoint(null);
      setArrowEndPoint(null);
      setIsDrawingArrow(false);

    }else if (addingArea && areaStart) {
      const createdArea = {
        x: Math.min(areaStart.x, x),
        y: Math.min(areaStart.y, y),
        width: Math.abs(x - areaStart.x),
        height: Math.abs(y - areaStart.y),
      };
      setAreas((areas) => [...areas, createdArea]);
      setAreaStart(null);
      setPreviewArea(null);
      setAddingGoal(false);
      setAddingCone(false);
      setAddingNumber(false);
      setAddingBall(false);
      setAddingPlayer(false);
      setAddingArrow(false);
    }
  };


   const Arrow = ({ start, end }) => {
      const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
        const drawArrow = (start, end, ctx) => {
          // Check if arrowStartPoint is not null
          
           // decide which type of arrow to draw
            switch (arrowType) {
              case 'pass':
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(start.x, start.y);
                ctx.lineTo(end.x, end.y);
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black'; // Arrow color
                ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                ctx.stroke();
                break;
              case 'run':
                // draw a dashed arrow
                break;
              case 'dribbling':
                // draw a wavy arrow
                break;
              case 'highball':
                // draw a slightly curved arrow
                break;
              default:
                break;
            }
          
        };
    
        drawArrow();
    
      }, [start, end]);
    
      return <canvas ref={canvasRef} />;
    };
    useEffect(drawArrow, [arrowType]);
    useEffect(() => {
      if (goalImage === null) {
        // If goalImage is not yet loaded, don't attempt to draw it
        return;
      }

      const canvas = canvasRef.current;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
      // Clear the field
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
      // Redraw the field
      drawField();
    
      // Draw each player
      for (const player of players) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(player.x, player.y, 10 /* player size */, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'blue'; // player color
        ctx.fill();
    
        // Draw player number
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white'; // text color
        ctx.fillText(player.id, player.x-3, player.y+3); // adjust these values as needed
      }
    
  // Create a new image object and set its source
  const ballImg = new Image();
  ballImg.src = ballImage;

  // Draw each ball when the image has loaded
  ballImg.onload = () => {
    for (const ball of balls) {
      // Draw the image at the ball's position
      ctx.drawImage(ballImg, ball.x, ball.y, 16, 16); // Adjust the size (14, 14 here) as needed
    }
  };
    
// Draw arrows
for (const arrow of arrows) {
  Arrow(arrow.start, arrow.end, ctx);
}

      // Draw each area
      for (const area of areas) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(area.x, area.y, area.width, area.height);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)';
        ctx.fill();
      }

    }, [players, balls, mousePosition, areas, arrows]);
```

I want that the arrow appears when dragging and dropping. The Arrow shows on Mouse down but as soon as I lift my Mouse the arrow disappears.